# Compare token plain text with token encrypted from Devise , Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bcrypt

I have app - `Rails 5` with `Devise`. When user request new password, `Devise` generates token (plain text) which is send to the user email. After that `Devise` encrypt this token and save it to the database.

What I want is when user clicks to the link with token (plain text) for changing password, to compare this token from `GET` variable with this saved in the database (which is encrypted).

I see that `Devise` has method for this (validating URL token with encrypted in the database):

```
resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
```

, but it is for  registration (when user validates his email - confirmation link).

What I am trying is:

```
token_hash = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:reset_password_token])
user = User.find_by({reset_password_token: token_hash})
```

`params[:reset_password_token]` is the right value, but it returns `nil`. 
The token is valid, because after that I can change the password.

If I do:

```
user = User.find_by_email('some email') # because I know which email is
token = BCrypt::Password.new(user.reset_password_token)
```

I am getting this error:

> BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash Exception: invalid hash

, but same code works, with `user.encrypted_password`.

I know how to get token from the URL, but how to compare it with this one saved in the database, which is encrypted ?

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Devise gem encryption and decryption of password token

Devise gem has TokenGenerator class.Whenever you send reset_password_instructions
it generates  friendly_token and corresponding encrypted token.It sends friendly_tokens in the email and stores encrypted token in Table.Now, whenever you submit that token It will encrypt your password token and compares it with one that is stored in your table.

Below example will elaborate more

### Encryption

**syntax**:

> Devise.token_generator.generate(class_name,column_name)

**Example**:

```
Devise.token_generator.generate(User,:reset_password_token)
["J9SkM77VENGQRZirVnoq", "2942dd29f8ddbd96ff59373a92bd3430e437f038efb81639532311a8d3a83467"]
```

So, `*generate*` method returns array with friendly_token at index 0 which will be sent to your email  and a encrypted token at index 1 which will be stored in Table.

### Decryption

**syntax:**

> Devise.token_generator.digest(class_name,column_name, password_token)

**Example**

```
Devise.token_generator.digest(User,:reset_password_token, "J9SkM77VENGQRZirVnoq")
"2942dd29f8ddbd96ff59373a92bd3430e437f038efb81639532311a8d3a83467"
```